# How to calculate the achieved difficulty of a mined block

Tags: block-explorer, hash-verification, difficulty-algorithm, difficulty, monero-hash

How does monero calculate the achieved difficulty of a mined block given a pow hash from randomx. I dont know if this is perhaps the correct place to ask this. If its not is there a better place to pin this?
I looked here: [How can I tell what difficulty my solution is?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/how-can-i-tell-what-difficulty-my-solution-is/8495)

From that I copied the code to a nodejs scratchpad: https://repl.it/repls/KaleidoscopicLiquidVideogames:

```
const baseDiff = bignum('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF', 16);

Buffer.prototype.toByteArray = function () {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(this, 0);
};

let hex_hash = "9ac67c5a2793861093ffa3f3fbeeffd8e9971fe555f59a0735c2d50500000000";
var hash = new Buffer.from(hex_hash,'hex');
var hashArray = hash.toByteArray().reverse();
var hashNum = bignum.fromBuffer(Buffer.from(hashArray));
var hashDiff = baseDiff.div(hashNum);
console.log(hashDiff.toString());
console.log("done");
```

I also wrote code in rust, the values match from the rust vs nodejs. But they do not match the difficulty from the block explorers.
The code above results in difficulty achieved: 188434043243
While the block explorer: https://xmrchain.net/block/2196393
results in 159730146809.

Dotting the differences again here for easy viewing:

188434043243

159730146809

Why is there a difference there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there a difference there?

The difficulty displayed on block explorers is the difficulty the hash has to be *greater than*, not what difficulty the hash *is*.